# Biju Control by Hashirama and Uchiha

Tags: naruto

Why are the Uchiha able to control Biju or at least the nine tails?

Why was Hashirama able to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Well its due to the Sharingan, the sharingan is a direct derivative of the rinnegan which the Sage of Six Paths used to CREATE the 9 beasts, this is For most Uchiha

As for Hashirama, he didnt exactly control the 9 tails, he just put a restriction jutsu on it, restricting its movement, he does have a lot of jutsus, he also does have this beast restriction ability similar to Yamato, but to "Control" is a bit of a stretch